# How does form buttons can select checkboxes in the next page?

Tags: php, url, checkbox

I have some buttons in a first_page.php, and some checkboxes in a second_page.php.
I need to select the corresponding checkbox with a query string to get this:
When "first value button" is pressed --> "second_page.php" with "my first value" checkbox already selected.

first_page.php :

```
<form action="second_page.php">
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="first value button">
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="second value button">
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="third value button">
</form>
```

second_page.php :

```
<form name="name" method="post" action="#">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mybox[]" value="my first value"/>
    <span>my first box</span><br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="mybox[]" value="my second value"/>
    <span>my second box</span><br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="mybox[]" value="my third value"/>
    <span>my third box</span><br />
</form>
```

Comment: check the submitted data

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a name for each input to connect it to `$_POST` then in `second_page.php` you have to fetch the form value.
In first_page.php:

```
<form action="second_page.php" method="post">
    <input name="first_value_btn" class="btn" type="submit" value="first value button">
    <input name="second_value_btn" class="btn" type="submit" value="second value button">
    <input name="third_value_btn" class="btn" type="submit" value="third value button">
</form>
```

In second_page.php :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="prodotti[]" value="my first value" <?php echo ( isset($_POST['first_value_btn']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '');?> />
```

[Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

I've used `POST` as method in my example above, you could use `GET` instead and then replacing `$_POST` with `$_GET` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the Submit buttons names and then do a check on them on the next page:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox[]" value="my first value" <?php if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) { echo 'checked'; ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox[]" value="my first value" <?php if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) { echo 'checked'; ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox[]" value="my first value" <?php if (isset($_POST['submit3'])) { echo 'checked'; ?> />
```